# Object is missing when using Laravel Mail::later

Tags: laravel, queue

I have this code:

```
$data = ['user'=>User::find(1)];
Mail::later(5, 'email.template', $data, function($message){
  ...
})
```

And `email.template` have this:

```
print_r($user)
```

And when I received the email, the instance of $user is not User object. How could that happen? It is like the object is not referencing the right context. But when I use the Mail::send it is working fine. Little bit confused here.

Answer (score 11):

An Eloquent model is too big for a queue's job, which usually has a limit of 64kb.

I would advise you to use a regular queue job, pass it your user id, and fire off the email from there:

```php
$user_id = 1;

Queue::later(5, function () use ($user_id) {
    $data = ['user' => User::find($user_id)];

    Mail::send('email.template', $data, function ($message) {
        // ......
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. I've been looking for a way to use view presenter objects in my email templates.

Comment: I used a repository without a facade. I was able to use App:make to get me the repository object to work with as needed in mine.

Comment: hi @Joseph Silber if i use your method it works fine but if i try to send tablelike this `@component('mail::table')` in blade then i get error `No hint path defined for [mail]` only markable can help me to resolve my issue but i dont know how i make my view markable can you help me? here is my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582332/no-hint-path-defined-for-mail-in-laravel

Answer (score 3):

I took a similar approach to the other two answerers, but I implemented it using a view creator. I was able to retrieve the variables from the view with $view->getData(), and from that I retrieved the Eloquent Model. You could use the following in conjunction with Mail::later or Mail::queue.

```
View::creator('email.template', function($view)
{
    $view_data = $view->getData();

    if (isset($view_data['user_id']))
    {
        $user_id = $view_data['user_id'];
        $view->with('user', User::find(user_id));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Serializing Eloquent models can be a bit tricky.  The safest way is to just pass the ID to the Mail queue, and retrieve it when it comes back:

```
$data = ['user_id' => 1];
Mail::later(5,'email.template', $data, function ($message) {
   ...
});
```

And in your template (near the top):

```
<?php $user = User::find($user_id); ?>

.. rest of template
```

Or, as some other folks on IRC are suggesting, skip `Mail::later()` altogether and use `Queue::later()` instead.  Write your own handler that retrieves the models from the ids, then fires a `Mail::send()`.