# No hint path defined for [mail]. in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I know this question is asked many times but I could not found the answer
I am using this method to sending email

```
      Mail::send('dynamic_email_template',$data, function ($message) {

    $message->from('sales@scoopscreamery.pk', 'Contact');

    $message->to('hamzaqureshi401@gmail.com')->subject('Contact');

});
```

and getting this error `No hint path defined for [mail].`

**the error cause is i am sending table in email using `@component('mail::table')` in dynamic blade view so then i tried to differernt technique of code but in this i am getting mail but without (user input) {{ $name }} , {{ $email }} , {{ $messae1 }} can any one help me
yo get input data in email**

controller

```
$data =  [
        'name' =>     $request->name,
         'email' =>    $request->email,
          'message1' =>  $request->message1

    ];
Mail::to('hamzaqureshi401@gmail.com')->send(new \App\Mail\SendMail($data));
```

my model is

```
    class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Mail from Online Web Tutor')
                    ->markdown('dynamic_email_template',['data'=>$this->data]);
    
    }
```

and my dynamic blade is

```
    <p>Hi, This is {{ $name }}</p>
<p>I have some query like {{ $email }}.</p>
<p>It would be appriciative, if you gone through this feedback {{ $message1 }}.</p>
@component('mail::table')
| Laravel       | Table         | Example  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| --------:|
| Col 2 is      | Centered      | $10      |
| Col 3 is      | Right-Aligned | $20      |
@endcomponent
```

the error cause is I am sending table in email using @component('mail::table') in dynamic blade view so then I tried to differernt technique of code but in this I am getting mail but without (user input) {{ $name }} , {{ $email }} , {{ $messae1 }} can any one help me yo get input data in email

Comment: I think in the `dynamic_email_template.blade.php` you should be using `{{ $data['name'] }}` or `{{ Arr::get($data, 'name') }}` instead of `{{ $name }}`, etc.? You pass in `data` to the blade as one attribute, not `name`, `email`, `message1` (these are part of `data`).

Comment: i tried it but still missing data if i remove `@component('mail::table')` and use `Mail::send('dynamic_email_template',$data, function ($message) { $message->from('sales@scoopscreamery.pk', 'Contact'); $message->to('hamzaqureshi401@gmail.com')->subject('Contact'); });` then it work successfully

Comment: do you know any method in which i make dynamic blade markable and use as above code like this `public function build() {     return $this->markdown('emails.registered'); }`

Comment: <p>Hi, This is {{ $data['name'] }}</p>
<p>I have some query like {{ $data['email'] }}.</p>
<p>It would be appriciative, if you gone through this feedback {{ $data['message1'] }}.</p>  this will print detail as alistaircol mentioned . is there any other issue. if so can update post

Comment: where is your email blade file located? The way you are calling now, it should be under `resource/views/dynamic_email_template.blade.php`, correct?

Comment: @JohnLobo i have already posted complete question i have used it but still not getting user data

Comment: @HamzaQureshi i have tested same code which you mention in laravel with these changes <p>Hi, This is {{ $data['name'] }}</p>
<p>I have some query like {{ $data['email'] }}.</p>
<p>It would be appriciative, if you gone through this feedback {{ $data['message1'] }}.</p>  .based on this code i can see name, email message detial in email. once you check clearing cache

Comment: @JohnLobo i think i have issue in my laravel version 5.5.50 i tested this code on fresh install 7 version and it works fine and this same question is asked rarely but no one answered now i have updated my laravel to version 7 and now it works fine for me

Comment: @HamzaQureshi okay.glad that it solved your issue

Answer (score -1):

There may be some error in mail or notification inside your vendor folder re-export the component using publish command

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`